# Show Statusline in a e4 RCP Application and connect it to the ProgressView/EclipseJob progress

Tags: java, rcp, e4

I am using the Progress View as described here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/ProgressView.
When I start a Job using the following it is correctly displayed inside the ProgressView.

```
final Job job = Job.create("TestJob", (ICoreRunnable) monitor -> { 
        monitor.beginTask("TestJob", 100);
        // do job stuff
        monitor.worked(50);
        // do job stuff
        monitor.worked(50);
        monitor.done();
}
```

Now i also want to reflect the current Job progress in the Statusline.

My first problem is getting the Statusline to even be visible in my Workbench. From there the Statusline would need to be linked to the last Job progress made.

I tried using a trimbar at the bottom of my main window. To this trimbar i added a Toolcontrol that references my own implementation that holds a StatusLineManager instance. But i am hoping for a more standardized solution in getting the Statusline.

So I saw that WorkbenchWindowAdvisor can be subclassed. Here the StatusLine can be made visible together with an ProgressIndicator.

```
public class ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor extends WorkbenchWindowAdvisor {

    public ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor(IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer) {
        super(configurer);
    }

    @Override
    public void preWindowOpen() {
        IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer = getWindowConfigurer();
        configurer.setShowStatusLine(true);
        configurer.setShowProgressIndicator(true);
        configurer.setTitle("RCP Application");
    }
}
```

But i do not know where this is called or where i should call it.

I would appreciate any help or a different solution!

EDIT:

So I took another look at https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/ProgressView and saw that there is a ProgressRegion class mentioned. This is exactly what I want and when I add this class to my ToolControl it is linked to any job I start. Despite this I still get a NullPointerException when the Workbench first starts. Also there is no text displayed next to the progress indicator. Any ideas on that?

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-06-15 11:10:53.085
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.progress.internal.ProgressRegion' from bundle '480'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:990)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolControlRenderer.createWidget(ToolControlRenderer.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:992)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:738)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.TrimBarRenderer.processContents(TrimBarRenderer.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$1.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:738)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1076)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.progress.internal.ProgressContentProvider.<init>(ProgressContentProvider.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.progress.internal.ProgressContentProvider.<init>(ProgressContentProvider.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.progress.internal.ProgressViewerContentProvider.<init>(ProgressViewerContentProvider.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.progress.internal.ContentProviderFactory.getProgressViewerContentProvider(ContentProviderFactory.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.progress.internal.ProgressRegion.createContents(ProgressRegion.java:165)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    ... 47 more
```

Comment: WorkbenchWIndowAdvisor is Eclipse 3.x compatibility mode code, you can''t use it in a pure e4 app

Comment: I think it very unlikely that this progess code supports StatusLineManager either. You are going to have to look at the source code and modify it to update something like a plain `Label` in your Toolcontrol.

Comment: I would like to avoid implementing my own statusline. Is there no equivalent to `configurer.setShowStatusLine(true);` and `configurer.setShowProgressIndicator(true);` in e4?

Comment: No, e4 is very minimal it doesn't provide anything like that. There may be something in the progress view code but you will have to study it to find out.

Comment: @greg-449 Do you know where I can find a newer build of the ProgressView found here https://hudson.eclipse.org/platform/job/eclipse4-progress-view/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/releng/org.eclipse.e4.ui.progress.update/target/repository/? This one is from 2015, but i need the fixes of the newer versions. I am running into this issue https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=483601

Comment: This isn't a part of standard e4, I have no idea if anyone is maintaining it at all.

Comment: It definitely is being maintained here (maybe just barely): https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui/tree/master/bundles/org.eclipse.e4.ui.progress. There is a two year old fix that i need, but i only get access to a build from three years ago, as the jenkins build is disabled.